# 'SoundTap_HDViewController' does not implement the 'AVAudioPlayerDelegate'

Tags: objective-c

I get this error, and I dont get how to fix it?

class 'SoundTap_HDViewController' does not implement the 'AVAudioPlayerDelegate' protocol

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to conform to a protocol, you need to implement its required methods. AVAudioPlayerDelegate has no required methods, so you may be trying to call a delegate method without adding the protocol. Does your class look something like:

```
@interface SoundTap_HDViewController : NSObject <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
```

Protocols are listed between the <> and separated by commas.

Comment: Hmm, is that right for this code:
-(IBAction)playSound {
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"airhorn" ofType:@"wav"];
 AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL]; 
 theAudio.delegate = self;
        [theAudio play];

Comment: @Henry.  Why don't you just try it? "<AVAudioPlayerDelegate>" has 23 characters in it - far fewer than the number in your comment :)

Comment: @Henry. So you're assigning "self" as the delegate of the theAudio, so whatever "self" is should implement the AVAudioPlayerDelegate protocol as I indicated in the answer.

Comment: Sorry, mate, you'll have to post more code. Can't do much with "doesn't work." :)

Comment: @Henry: You probably need to add the #import for AVFoundation.